# Widget Entry de tkinter.No consigo capturar el valor introducido.Siempre coge 0

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, vscode

voy a intentar resumir lo maximo posible.Gracias de antemano.

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que haga lo siguiente:

1º Abrir ventana Tk para pedir un login  ( si password correcto,destruyo ventana y paso al 2 punto)

2º Cargar otra ventana Tk que seria la principal y dentro de esta ventana

> 1 - una caja de texto (CAJA)

> 2 - varios botones (ejemplo tabla_multiplicar) que generara texto en CAJA

3º Llamar a funciones de otro archivo que escribiran texto en CAJA

4º Al clickar en boton tabla_multiplicar, abrir nueva ventana Tk, pedir numero, generar texto en CAJA y destruir ventana

5º La idea seria crear boton para borrar contenido de CAJA y que se pueda seguir escribiendo texto en esta o que se haga de manera automatica esto cuando ya no cabe mas texto visualmente.

Expuesta la idea he realizado todo esto con funciones,como comente en mi primer post,no programo desde hace mas de 10 años y estoy empezando de nuevo.

La cosa es que no se si este programa se puede realizar solo con funciones y que quede de manera organizada y limpio.(Que no haya problemas despues con los mainloop ,que sea un programa bien estructurado)
Tambien lo he intentado pasar a clases todo esto,pero por una cosa o por otra no consigo todo lo que tiene que hacer,en resumen cuando lo hago con clases no consigo capturar la Entry del usuario y password,creo recordar que captura siempre " " y tampoco capturo la Entry del numero de la tabla de multiplicar siempre me coge 0.Y la funcion redirector que es llamanda cada vez que hago un print tampoco funciona con clases.
Le he dado tantas vueltas que tengo un cacao enorme con tanta prueba,estoy intentando leer todo lo que puedo porque me falta mucha base pero ahora mismo estoy estancado y necesito vuestra ayuda.

Nota *
Tambien he cambiado el linter en VSCode, utilizaba Pylint y me generaba muchos errores o avisos al importar tkinter con * ,por eso debajo vuelvo a importar lo que voy a utilizar.Ahora quiero probar Mypy ,pyright lo acabo de poner y ve algun error que Pylint ni detecta.
Cual teneis vosotros??
Es necesario marcar el linting de flake8,te aporta algo? teniendo pylint,mypy o pyright
Mi idea es trabajar con Pyright o Mypy con formato black.

He cambiado tantas veces el codigo que puede que haya algo que no este bien o que era diferente.

P.D : Tambien he intentado crear la ventana con Toplevel pero no me funciona.Cuantas ventanas Tk es posible abrir,por lo que he leido la idea es trabajar solo con una y trabajar con frames,no se si estoy equivocado.

Codigo

```
import sys
    
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Text
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import Entry
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import StringVar
# from tkinter import IntVar


"""
En esta funcion creamos la ventana del login y cuando colocamos la contraseña
correcta y pulsamos login,destruimos la ventana.
"""

def ventana_login():
    ventana_login = Tk()
    ventana_login.eval("tk::PlaceWindow . center")
    ventana_login.title("MylittleWorld Login")
    ventana_login.geometry("360x180")
    Label(text="Introduce tu usuario y contraseña para entrar a tu mundo",
               fg="black").place(x=20, y=10)
    Label(text="Username :", fg="black").place(x=20, y=60)
    Label(text="Password :", fg="black").place(x=20, y=90)
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()
    Entry(textvariable=username).place(x=90, y=60)
    Entry(textvariable=password, show="*").place(x=90, y=90)

    def login():
        if username.get() == "yo" and password.get() == "yo":
            messagebox.showinfo(title="Login Status",
                                message="You have logged in")
            ventana_login.destroy()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror(title="Login Error",
                                 message="User/Password Incorrect")

    Button(text="Login", command=login).place(x=90, y=120)
    ventana_login.mainloop()


def ventana_tabla():
    ventana_tabla = Tk()
    # ventana_tabla.eval("tk::PlaceWindow . center")
    # ventana_tabla = Toplevel(ventana_principal)
    ventana_tabla.eval("tk::PlaceWindow . center")
    ventana_tabla.title("Tabla Multiplicar")
    ventana_tabla.geometry("360x180")
    # ventana_principal.iconify()
    Label(ventana_tabla, text="Introduce el Numero de la tabla de"
          "multiplar que quieres aprender.\n"
          "El numero tiene que ser positivo.").pack()
    # numero = StringVar()        
    numero = IntVar()
    e1 = Entry(ventana_tabla, textvariable=numero).pack()
    # e1.bind('<Return>', tablaMulti)
    # ventana_tabla.update()
    # ventana_tabla.bind('<Return>', tablaMulti)
    numeroInt = int(numero.get())
    
    
    def tablaMulti():
        # global numeroInt
        numeroInt = int(numero.get())
        comprobar = True
        while comprobar == True:
            """
            numero = int(input("Introduce el Numero de la tabla de multiplar que"
                            " quieres aprender."+"\nEl numero "
                            "tiene que ser positivo: "))
            """
            if numeroInt >= 0:
                for i in range (0, 11):
                    print(numeroInt, "por", i, "es =", numeroInt*i)
                comprobar = False
            else:
                print("El numero ingresado no es correcto, "
                     "recuerda que tiene que ser un numero positivo.")

    
    Button(ventana_tabla, text='Generar',
           command=tablaMulti).pack()
    # ventana_tabla.mainloop()
    
"""
En esta funcion creamos la ventana principal del programa.
"""
def ventana_principal():
    ventana_principal = Tk()
    ventana_principal.state("zoomed")
    ventana_principal.title("MylittleWorld System")
    # ventana_principal.config(bg="#000000")
    # Label(text="Tablas de Multiplicar :").place(x=320, y=460)
    button1 = Button(ventana_principal, text='Tablas de Multiplicar',
                     command=ventana_tabla)
    button1.place(x=1240,y=20)
    cajadetexto = Text(ventana_principal, bg="black", fg="orange",
                       insertbackground="green", height=25, width=150,
                       insertofftime=400)
    cajadetexto.place(x=10, y=20)
"""
funcion que cuando haces un print lo pasa todo a una caja de texto de la ventana principal
"""

    def redirector(inputStr):
        cajadetexto.insert(INSERT, inputStr)
        # ventana_principal.update_idletasks()
        ventana_principal.update()

    sys.stdout.write = redirector

    otra_funcion()
    ventana_principal.mainloop()




ventana_login()
ventana_principal()
```

Espero que podais echarme una mano.
Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código que proporcionas es bastante farragoso y no he conseguido hacerlo funcionar correctamente.

Te propongo otro enfoque que usa varias estrategias para hacerlo más fácil de leer y de mantener:

- Programación orientada a objetos. Mediante clases, cada una de las "pantallas" (que en lo sucesivo llamaré `Paneles`) encapsula sus propios widgets, que son creados en su `__init__()` y mostrados cuando se le pida.
- Una única ventana "top-level" que es la ventana raíz. Dentro de ella habría varios frames (tus diferentes "pantallas") de los cuales sólo habría uno visible en cada momento.
- Un mecanismo genérico para conectar entre sí los frames en un "flujo" que permita especificar "después de este Panel viene este otro".

La idea es entonces crear tres paneles (implementados como `tk.Frame`):

1. El panel que pide el login.
2. El panel que muestra una especie de terminal negra con el botón "Generar tabla"
3. El panel que pide al usuario un número con el cual generar la tabla.

Cada panel tiene una función `.mostrar()` que hace ese panel visible, y tiene otra función `.siguiente()` que debe invocar el `.mostrar()` del panel que deba aparecer después.

Habría una clase más que crearía estos tres paneles y los conectaría entre sí en la secuencia correcta haciendo que el método `.siguiente` de cada panel sea el método `.mostrar` del panel que corresponda.

La ejecución comenzaría mostrando el panel 1, y al recibir la clave correcta éste llamará a `self.siguiente()`, lo que mostrará el panel 2. Al pulsar el botón "Tablas de multiplicar" éste llamará a `self.siguiente()`,  lo que mostrará el panel 3. Cuando el usuario meta el número y pulse "Generar" se llamará a `self.siguiente()` lo que volverá a mostrar el panel 2, y así sucesivamente. En cualquiera de los paneles se puede cerrar la ventana y el programa termina (ya que la única ventana que hay es `root` y cuando ésta se cierra el programa finaliza).

Este es el código que hace lo descrito, y que incluye la clase general `Panel` de la que heredan los tres paneles antes descritos:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Panel(tk.Frame):
    """Clase genérica para mostrar un Frame con un cierto título y
    tamaño dados, centrado en la pantalla"""

    def __init__(self, master, titulo="Sin título", ancho=360, alto=180):
        super().__init__()
        self.master: tk.Tk = master
        self.siguiente = (
            lambda: None
        )  # Valor por defecto no útil. El programa principal debe asignar otro
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.ancho = ancho
        self.alto = alto
        self.x = (self.master.winfo_screenwidth() - self.ancho) // 2
        self.y = (self.master.winfo_screenheight() - self.alto) // 2

    def mostrar(self):
        self.master.title(self.titulo)
        self.master.geometry(
            "{}x{}+{}+{}".format(self.ancho, self.alto, self.x, self.y)
        )
        self.lift()


class Login(Panel):
    """Panel de login. Cuando el nombre y contraseña se introducen bien
    llamará a self.siguiente() para pasar al siguiente Panel"""

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Label(
            self,
            text="Introduce tu usuario y contraseña para entrar a tu mundo",
            fg="black",
        ).place(x=20, y=10)
        tk.Label(self, text="Username :", fg="black").place(x=20, y=60)
        tk.Label(self, text="Password :", fg="black").place(x=20, y=90)
        self.username = tk.StringVar()
        self.password = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.username).place(x=90, y=60)
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.password, show="*").place(x=90, y=90)
        tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self.login).place(x=90, y=120)

    def login(self):
        if self.username.get() == "yo" and self.password.get() == "yo":
            messagebox.showinfo(title="Login Status", message="You have logged in")
            self.siguiente()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror(title="Login Error", message="User/Password Incorrect")


class VentanaPrincipal(Panel):
    """Panel que muestra una "terminal" negra y el botón para generar la tabla.
    Al pulsar ese botón llama a self.siguiente() para mostrar el panel que
    pide un número al usuario"""

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Label(self, text="Tablas de Multiplicar :").place(x=320, y=300)
        button1 = tk.Button(
            self, text="Tablas de Multiplicar", command=self.mostrar_tabla
        )
        button1.place(x=400, y=20)
        self.cajadetexto = tk.Text(
            self,
            bg="black",
            fg="orange",
            insertbackground="green",
            height=25,
            width=30,
            insertofftime=400,
        )
        self.cajadetexto.place(x=10, y=20)
        sys.stdout.write = self.redirector

    def redirector(self, inputStr):
        """Esta función redirige la salida estándar a la "terminal" del panel"""
        self.cajadetexto.insert(tk.INSERT, inputStr)
        return 0

    def mostrar_tabla(self):
        # Limpiar antes
        self.cajadetexto.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        self.siguiente()


class VentanaTabla(Panel):
    """Este panel pide un número al usuario y verifica que sea correcto. Si no
    lo es imprime un mensaje de error, si lo es imprime una tabla de 
    multiplicar. En ambos casos llama a self.siguiente() para pasar
    al panel siguiente, que en este caso sería el antes visto donde
    se haría visible el mensaje o tabla impresos."""

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Label(
            self,
            text="Introduce el Numero de la tabla de"
            "multiplar que quieres aprender.\n"
            "El numero tiene que ser positivo.",
        ).pack()
        self.numero = tk.IntVar()
        self.e1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.numero)
        self.e1.pack()
        self.update()
        tk.Button(self, text="Generar", command=self.tablaMulti).pack()

    def tablaMulti(self):
        try: # Capturamos posible excepción por si introduce algo que
             # no es un número
            numeroInt = int(self.numero.get())
        except:
            numeroInt = -1
        if numeroInt >= 0:
            salida = []
            for i in range(0, 11):
                salida.append("{} por {} es = {}".format(numeroInt, i, numeroInt * i))
            print("\n".join(salida))
        else:
            print("El número introducido no es correcto")
        self.siguiente()


class App(tk.Frame):
    """Clase principal que crea los diferentes paneles y los "conecta" entre
    sí de modo que la función .siguiente() de uno llame al .mostrar() del
    siguiente"""

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()

        # Creacion de los tres paneles
        login = Login(master, titulo="MyLittleWorld Login", ancho=360, alto=180)
        principal = VentanaPrincipal(
            master, titulo="MyLittleWorld System", ancho=600, alto=400
        )
        tabla = VentanaTabla(master, titulo="Tabla multiplicar", ancho=360, alto=180)

        # Conexión entre sí de la secuencia
        login.siguiente = principal.mostrar
        principal.siguiente = tabla.mostrar
        tabla.siguiente = principal.mostrar

        # Configuración de los tres frames
        for frame in (login, principal, tabla):
            frame.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        # Empezamos por el de login
        login.mostrar()


def main():
    """El programa principal instancia la ventana raiz Tk() y la usa
    para inicializar la aplicación y el bucle de eventos"""
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Estas son unas capturas de pantalla de la ejecución:

1. Panel de login

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Panel principal al que se accede tras dar la contraseña correcta

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Panel que pide la entrada del usuario, al que se llega tras pulsar "Tablas de multiplicar" en el panel anterior

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. Vuelta al panel principal una vez se ha pulsado el botón "Generar"

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]